# Java Hamcrest matcher equivalent to sql join operation

Tags: java, filter, matcher, hamcrest

I have 2 lists containing objects, eg:
**list1** has object person
person has the following attributes:
*name, id, address*

**list2** has object employee
employee has the following attributes:
*orgId, id, salary*

the id in employee is equal to the id in person.

I am trying to filter/get all the employees where name is any of `['john', 'wick', 'tom']`

This is easily doable if I was working with SQL statements but is there an equivalent for this in Java hamcrest or other matchers?

I was on the following line when I got stuck.

```
List selected = select(
                      list2,
                      having(
                            on(Employee.class).getId(),
                            equalTo("")
                      )
                );
```

Answer (score 2):

More than a matcher, you might want to use streams and predicates:

```
List<Person> selected = list1.stream()
    .filter(person -> list2.stream().anyMatch(employee -> employee.getId().equals(person.getId())))
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: am limited to java 7

Comment: Oh, I see. Sad to hear that. Is [retrolambda](https://github.com/luontola/retrolambda) and/or [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) a possibility?